# if $f+g$ is nonincreasing is that amplies $f$ and $g$ are nonincreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f$ and $g$ be two positive real functions such that $f+g$ is nonincreasing.
Can we say that $f$ and $g$ are nonincreasing ? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

$$ \arctan(x) + \arctan(1/x) = \pi/2 $$ for $x>0$

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=e^{-x}(1.2+\sin x)$$
$$g(x)=e^{-x}(1.2-\sin x)$$

Answer (score 2):

Take any function that is entirely positive but sometimes increasing and decreasing, for example $$f(x)=sin(x) + 2.$$ Then, if you want a visual explanation, "mirror" this function along a horizontal line s.t. the mirrored function is also always positive, e.g. $$g(x)=-sin(x)+2.$$ Both are positive, are increasing and decreasing, and their sum is just $$f+g(x)=2,$$ hence nonincreasing.